# Why I got an error when running "hdfs namenode -format" command during Hadoop Installation Error on Windows10?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I typed "hdfs namenode -format" command to set the namenode. But I got an error like below.

```
2019-10-20 04:15:57,279 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
2019-10-20 04:15:57,280 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2019-10-20 04:15:57,281 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
2019-10-20 04:15:57,282 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
2019-10-20 04:15:57,372 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-638256157-172.17.18.209-1571516157358
2019-10-20 04:15:57,377 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2044)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
2019-10-20 04:15:57,388 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2019-10-20 04:15:57,395 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at YXYstyle/172.17.18.209
************************************************************/
```

I downloaded hadoop-3.2.1 and winutils from https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils to simply override the bin directory like below.
[This is the list of hadoop-3.2.1/bin directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzS1G.png)

Below is the core-site.xml configuration.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The hadoop-env.cmd (BTW: I already set the enviroment variable of JAVA_HOME):

```
@rem The java implementation to use.  Required.
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

@rem The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
@rem set JSVC_HOME=%JSVC_HOME%
```

The hdfs-site.xml :

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop-3.2.1/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop-3.2.1/data/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The yarn-site.xml :

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

I just got into hadoop and totally new about it.
Could anyone help on it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug in 3.2.1 version. You can see that this is fixed just four days ago. It was fine in earlier versions. I tested with 2.6.0 and it is working but not with 3.2.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-14890

Comment: Thanks, I intalled it successfully on 3.1.2 version. That's a version bug. Case closed.